# Why we can call `__mod__` function with string in Python?

Tags: python

I am reading python source code:
https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l621

```
 def __repr__(self):

        if not self:

            return '%s()' % self.__class__.__name__

        items = ', '.join(map('%r: %r'.__mod__, self.most_common()))

        return '%s({%s})' % (self.__class__.__name__, items)
```

form the doc:

```
operator.mod(a, b)
operator.__mod__(a, b)¶
Return a % b.
```

This is right as i think,

But why `'%r: %r'.__mod__` is right?

Comment: Because `__mod__` implements the string format property we are accustomed to e.g. `'%r: %r' % (5,2)` is implemented via `__mod__`. It's just operator overloading, I believe.

Comment: It calls old string formatting operator `"%r: %r" % (o1, o2)` *for each* (that's what `map` does) pair yield from `self.most_common()`.

Comment: @Rogalski i am not sure `%r: %r'.__mod__`, i never see this usage.

Comment: @BlackMamba I've explained why its `__mod__` and not `__mod__()` in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why Strings Have `__mod__`

`__mod__` implements the behaviour of the `%` operator in Python. For strings, the `%` operator is [overloaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading) to give us string formatting options. Where usually `a % b` would force the evaluation of `a mod b` if `a` and `b` are numbers, for strings, we can *change* the behaviour of `%` so that `a % b` actually *inserts* the elements of `b` into `a` if `a` is a string.

The way operator overloading works in Python is that each infix operator symbol - `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`, etc. (and, as of Python 3.5, the [matrix multiplication operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-465-a-dedicated-infix-operator-for-matrix-multiplication) `@`) - corresponds to a specific method in the base definition of the class it's being called on. For `+`, it is `__add__()`, for example. For `%`, it is `__mod__()`. We can *overload* these methods by simply redefining them within a class.

If I have class `Foo`, and `Foo` implements a member function `__add__(self, other)`, I can potentially make `Foo() + bar` behave very differently than what the usual definition of `+` is.

In other words, the string formatting technique

```
'%s: %s' % (5,2)
```

in Python actually calls

```
'%s: %s'.__mod__((5,2))
```

under the hood, where `__mod__` is defined for objects belonging to class `string`. The way `__mod__()` is implemented for strings yields, in this case, just `5: 2`, rather than the ridiculous interpretation of `'%s : %s' mod (5,2)`

---

### Why `__mod__` in `map` and not `__mod__()`

In the specific case of `map('%r: %r'.__mod__, self.most_common())`, what's happening is that the function *pointer* (for want of a better word - note that Python doesn't *have* pointers, but it doesn't hurt to think in that way for a moment) `__mod__` is being applied to each of the elements in `self.most_common()`, rather than the function `__mod__()`.

This is no different than doing, say, `map(int, "52")`. We don't pass the function *invocation* `int()`, we pass a reference to the function as `int` and expect the function to be invoked by `map` with the second arguments to `map`. i.e. that `int()` will be invoked over each element of "52".

We can't do `map('%r: %r'.__mod__(), self.most_common())` for exactly this reason. The function `'%r: %r'.__mod__()` would be invoked *without* the appropriate parameters passed in and return an error - what we want instead is a reference to the function `__mod__()` than we can deference and invoke whenever we like, which is accomplished by calling `__mod__`.

---

### A C++ Analogy

The behaviour of `__mod__` versus `__mod__()` is really no different than how function pointers work in C++: a function pointer for `foo()` is denoted by just `foo` i.e. without the parentheses. Something *analogous* - but not quite the same - happens here. I introduce this here because it may make the distinction clearer, because on the surface pointers look very similar to what is happening and introducing pointers leads to a fairly familiar mode of thinking which is good enough for this specific purpose.

In C++, we can pass function pointers to other functions and introduce a form of currying - you can then invoke the function pointer on elements through regular `foo()` syntax *inside* another function, for example. In Python, we don't have pointers - we have *wrapper* objects that can reference the underlying memory location (but prevent raw access to it). For our purposes, though, the net effect is the same. @Bukuriu explores the difference in the comments.

Basically, `__mod__()` forces an *evaluation* with no parameters; `__mod__` returns a *pointer* to `__mod__()` than can *then* be invoked by another function on suitable parameters. Internally, that is what `map` does: take a function pointer (again, this is an analogy), and then deference and evaluate it on another element.

You can see this yourself: calling `'%s'.__mod__` returns

```
<method-wrapper '__mod__' of str object at 0x7f92ed464690>
```

i.e. a *wrapper* object with a reference to the memory address to the function. Meanwhile, calling `'%s'.__mod__()` returns an error:

```
TypeError: expected 1 arguments, got 0
```

because the extra parentheses invoked an *evaluation* of `__mod__` and found there were no arguments.

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers. Also note that `s.__mod__ is s.__mod__` is *false*. Everytime you reference the `__mod__` attribute a new `method-wrapper` object is created and returned.  I wouldn't mention C++ because 1) the OP didn't mention it 2) It's completely different from Python and it will only create confusion  3) You are giving false information based on C++ that simply isn't true in python, like that there exist function pointers etc. which is false.

Comment: @Bakuriu I know Python doesn't have pointers. The way I've worded this answer, I think, makes it clear I was drawing an analogy. But you're right, I'll make that more explicit.

Comment: @Bakuriu Edited. I disagree that bringing C++ into the mix adds confusion - the most popular flavour of Python is CPython, after all - but you're right, making the distinction between Python and C++ is very crucial here. Let me know if you have other suggestions. :)

Answer (score 2):

As in http://rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html says

```
__mod__(self, other)
    Implements modulo using the % operator.
```

This means when you do string formating `'%s' % '123'` you do `'%s'.__mod__('123')`

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this case down.

Essential parts of this complex line are:

```
seq = self.most_common()
string_representations = map('%r: %r'.__mod__, seq)
items = ', '.join(string_representations)
```

First line calls `Counter`s method to retrieve top counts from dictionary. Third line joins string representations to single comma-separated string. Both are fairly trivial.

Second line:
- calls `map` - which tells us it calls some function for each element in `seq`
- first argument of map defines function as `'%r: %r'.__mod__`

We know that operator overloading is done by redefining [`__magic_methods__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) in class declaration. Strings happens to define `__mod__` as interpolation operation.

Also, we know that most of operations are just [syntactic sugars around those magic methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

What happens here is magic method being referred explicitly instead of via `a % b` syntactic sugar. Or, from different perspective, underlining implementation detail is used perform operation instead of standard form.

Second line is roughy equivalent to:

```
string_representations = ['%r: %r' % o for o in seq]
```