# Python modulus assignment (%=) for string formatting

Tags: python, string

Django, [for example](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f1374f34da90e1d16e272c89ac07786e907e3778/django/core/exceptions.py#L169), uses this code to cater for [`ValidationError` exceptions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror)

```
>>> message = 'My name is %(name)s'
>>> params = {'name': 'George'}
>>> message %= params
>>> print(message):
'My name is George'
```

The only documentation I managed to find on `%=` is [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus_assignment.html) where it is called a `modulus assignment operator`.

I really do not understand why it works with the old style formatting (`%`) and I cannot understand how this will be used with the new style formatting (`str.format()`).

Does the new style formatting render this code redundant?

Comment: just looks lazy to me. But ` x %= y ` is essentially equivalent to `x =  x%y` so it makes sense that it works. And yes, `%` style formatting is pretty old and you should use new style formatting

Comment: I am not sure what are you talking about when you say "old style" and "new style", but Python works in a way that, overriding certain method names, you can define the behaviour of some class' instances when they use certain operator. For example, when you create a class and add a method called `__mod__`, that method will define how the instances of the class will behave when operated with `%` operator. There is more information about this subject in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36442389/3692177)

Comment: @SebasSBM Thank you, this link is clear on why `%=` works. For the [new style, old style](https://pyformat.info/) I am refering to [% vs str.format()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format).

Comment: @raratiru IMHO, `str.format` is a workaround, some kind of [wrapper function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function) to prevent some funny use cases of `%` operator with strings. The first answer of the question you linked shows a use-case with tuples (useful to parse multiple values at once into strings), where, to prevent TypeMismatch errors, you "hack" a single value as a 1-len tuple. The new `format` method probably wraps the original functionality to prevent this kind of cases right away, among other things, which helps to write cleaner code. And that's great.

Comment: @SebasSBM I understand your point, it seemed strange that Django keeps -in this occasion only- the old formatting. Should it be because there is no equivalent of `%=` operator in the new formatting but at the same time this is not redundant, it is just old fashioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of str (in both 2x and 3x). It shorthands `message = message % params` with message as format string. You can read up on similar operators like `*= aka __imul__` [here](http://www.trytoprogram.com/python-programming/python-operator-overloading/).

The string/modulus operator is for "old python formatting", which you can read about here along with the history of [new and old](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/).